# AntD List loadMore prop

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, antd

How can I implement the loadMore prop in AntD using List? I already have the api with limit. I'm using fetch API but not Reqwest like what AntD used in their example

This is my component

```
<List
 itemLayout="horizontal"
 loading={isLoading}
 loadMore={isLoadMore}
 dataSource={dataSource}
 renderItem={(item, i) => (
  <List.Item>
    <Skeleton
      avatar={false}
      title={false}
      loading={isSkeleton}
      active
    >
    <List.Item.Meta title={item.desc} description={item.type} /> 
      <div>
        content here
      </div>
     </Skeleton>
   </List.Item>
  )} 
/>
```

I'm calling it from another file

```
const CalendarManagement = () => {
  const holidayListDay = [];
  const limit = 3;
  const [isHolidayDay, setHolidayDay] = useState(holidayListDay);
  const [isLoadingHoliday, setLoadingHoliday] = useState(false);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isSkeleton: false,
  })

  //Fetching API here
  const fetchHolidayList = async () =>
   await CalendarManagementAPI.getHolidayList(limit)
    .then(data => {
      setHolidayDay(data);
      setLoadingHoliday(false);
    })
    .catch(error =>
      setState({
        error,
        isLoadingHoliday: false,
      })
    );

    useEffect(() => {
     fetchHolidayList();
     setLoadingHoliday(true);

      setState({
        ...state,
        isSkeleton: false,
      });
    }

    const onLoadMore = () => {
     setState({
      ...state,
      isSkeleton: true,
      isLoadingHoliday: true,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      setHolidayDay(isHolidayDay);
      setState({
        ...state,
        isSkeleton: false,
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  const loadMoreHoliday =
   !state.isLoadingHoliday && !state.isSkeleton ? (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={onLoadMore}>View More</Button>
    </div>
  ) : null;



  <CalendarHolidayList
   dataSource={isHolidayDay}
   isLoading={isLoadingHoliday}
   isLoadMore={loadMoreHoliday}
   isSkeleton={state.isSkeleton}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`react-infinite-scroller`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller) package. it is very stright forward and you can implement it with any UI related packages.

just reading trough documentation would help you out.

Comment: I prefer to have a trigger on it. Will that be possible on that package?

Comment: yes sure , you just implement a load more functionality on your component for your endpoint pagination and you good to go :)